# Jasmine spec run inside the maven build

Tags: javascript, jasmine

[image]Hello,

I have a maven project where i created a couple of jasmine specs to run.
the problem i'm facing is that when i open the SpecRunner.html i can see that the specs are executed; i get 11 specs, 0 failed.

when during the build in the console, i get 0 spec 0 failed.

i don't know what i'm doing wrong in the pom file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jsSrcDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/ags_gap_app/Views</jsSrcDir>
                    <jsTestSrcDir>${basedir}/src/main/test</jsTestSrcDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

can sombody help me please
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your directories are wrongly spelled try something like this.

```
<jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/Views/</jsSrcDir>
<jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/ags_gal_app/test/</jsTestSrcDir>
```